# Send/Receive SMS programmatically

Tags: sms, twilio, sms-gateway

I have a requirement where I am using Twilio ML to send/receive message. I have purchased one Twilio Number as well, but my requirement is to use Client's carrier operator Number directly (AT&T or Airtel or any other operator) as my client dont want to add new Twilio Number for contact. Is there any workaround for the same? I know Porting to Twilio is a way, but apart from that any means where I can receive SMS of his/her number and can send SMS from his/her number using any tool?

Comment: Is this for contacting people in the USA? text spoofing is impossible in the usa but a plausible Idea for other contries.

Comment: not for spoofing, this is for helping customer to book service/ asks for QnA with Twilio bot. I receive message from user and will respond back programatically

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the Developer Preview [Hosted Numbers](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/hosted-numbers) product. There are some restrictions on the number types that may be hosted (covered in the FAQ), but basically it allows the SMS portion of the number to be hosted by Twilio, so no need to port the number for both voice and SMS.

Comment: Thanks Alan, They have mentioned mobile number is not eligible :/ All our clients are small-to-mid businesses and they are operating with private carrier mobile phones only.